# Should I put all four HDDs into NAS even if I do not need the their full capacity right now?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, synology, synology-diskstation

I have new four-bay NAS (Synology DS418play) and four new 4TB HDDs (WD40EFRX). Is it advisable to put all disks into NAS right away, even if I do not need the full storage capacity? Or should I put just two of them (one for storage one for redundancy) and add the remaining two disks later when I need to increase the capacity? I guess, I stick to Synology Hybrid RAID mode. Which of the two approaches is preferable and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all 4 disks into a Raid 6, then 2 drives can fail -> 8 TB useable

Raid 5 over 3 disks might be faster, but then only one should fail -> also 8 TB capacity - you can keep the 4th as cold standby or [hot standby](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/hotspare).

Standard Raid levels are also explained by [Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/general).

With the [RAID Calculator](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/RAID_calculator?hdds=4%20TB|4%20TB|4%20TB|4%20TB) you will see that capacities of Raid 5 can be compared with SHR. Raid 6 can be compared with SHR-2.

According to [this description of SHR](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID_SHR) you will see that it may be useful, if you later want to replace the drives with larger disks without downtime - but keep in mind that you still should have backups.
On the other hand you can not use SHR, if you want to add a [2nd redundant NAS](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Disaster_Recovery/What_should_I_do_to_deploy_HA_with_SHR).

Comment: If you have spare HDD's then over time you will probably use them in something else then when one from the nas fails ..... no disks. Always fill up the NAS